# In Jasper Reports, how to store the result of a sql query in a variable?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In Jasper Reports, how may I execute a sql query and store the result in a variable? This result should be accessed using $V{varName}.

EDIT: I have a subdataset defined like this:

```
<subDataset name="current_user" uuid="f8453e1d-8d55-4157-a8fd-aa04986e1cd5">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="MySQL Local"/>
    <parameter name="u" class="java.lang.Integer">
      <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
      <![CDATA[select first_name, last_name from users where id_user = $P{u}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="first_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="last_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

I want the first and last name of a user, to be stored in a variable, and then this variable to be displayed in several fields (the variable is reused). How can I do that?

Comment: "¿How may I execute a sql query and store the result in a variable?"  English does not have the `¿` as part of a question (so don't include it).

Answer (score 0):

Your value come from sql query store in field. You can store that value in variable lie this. 
First make variable and with same class of field which value you want to store in variable .

```
<variable name="variable" class="java.lang.String">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Where field1 is name of field which value you want to store in variable.